# loop through list of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

i have a list of dictionaries. there are several points inside the list, some are multiple. When there is a multiple entry i want to calculate the average of the x and the y of this point. My problem is, that i don't know how to loop through the list of dictionaries to compare the ids of the points!

when i use something like that:

```
for i in list:
  for j in list:
    if i['id'] == j['id']:
      point = getPoint(i['geom'])
      ....
```

sorry, the formating is a little bit tricky... the second loop is inside the first one...
i think it compares the first entry of the list, so it's the same... so i have to start in the second loop with the second entry, but i can't do that with i-1 because i is the hole dictionary...
Someone an idea?
thanks in advance!

```
 for j in range(1, len(NEWPoint)):
      if i['gid']==j['gid']:
         allsamePoints.append(j)
      for k in allsamePoints:
         for l in range(1, len(allsamePoints)):
            if k['gid']==l['gid']:
                Point1 = k['geom']
                Point2=l['geom']
                X=(Point1.x()+Point2.x())/2
                Y=(Point1.y()+Point2.y())/2
                AVPoint = QgsPoint(X, Y)
                NEWReturnList.append({'gid': j['gid'], 'geom': AVPoint})
                del l
      for m in NEWReturnList:
          for n in range(1, len(NEWReturnList)):
              if m['gid']==n['gid']:
                 Point1 = m['geom']
                 Point2=n['geom']
                 X=(Point1.x()+Point2.x())/2
                 Y=(Point1.y()+Point2.y())/2
                 AVPoint = QgsPoint(X, Y)
                 NEWReturnList.append({'gid': j['gid'], 'geom': AVPoint})
                 del n
              else:
                 pass
```

ok, i think... at the moment thats more confusing :)...

Comment: What should happen if three or more elements have the same `'id'`? Do you want calculate the average of each pair of elements? Or do you want to cluster all the elements with the same `'id'` and take the average of the cluster?

Comment: Still not clear. Can you give sample input and expected output?

Comment: Why would you take i-1? You still loop through all possible matches.

Comment: ok, the input are points with ids. They are calculated in different ways so there are multiple entries. The result should be that i have one point in a list, which is the result of the average calculation.

i don't have a good solution for that at the moment... I will copy some code, one moment... but: it looks very confusing at the moment!

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: It's also helpful to post an example of what your data looks like, as well as an example of what you want out of it. Many times we go looking for the right answer to the wrong question. The best thing to do is say, "This is what I have... This is what I want... This is what I'm doing...". It takes a bit longer to write but it forces you to think about your algorithm, and it provides us a lot more flexibility in how we answer.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be changing the way you store your points, because as you already noticed, it's hard to get what you want out of it.

A much more useful structure would be a dict where the `id` maps to a list of points:

```
from collections import defaultdict
points_dict = defaultdict(list)

# make the new dict
for point in point_list:
    id = point["id"]
    points_dict[id].append(point['geom'])

def avg( lst ):
    """ average of a `lst` """
    return 1.0 * sum(lst)/len(lst)

# now its simple to get the average
for id in points_dict:
    print id, avg( points_dict[id] )
```

Comment: I retracted the comment I was in the middle of writing as THC4k is correct. A list of dicts is not ideal at all -- more naturally, you have ONE dict in which you can deduplicate the points first. +1

However, THC4k, it would be nice if you added code on how to build such a dict from the list, to make it clearer for the OP.

Comment: so, when i go with the points_dict[id].append(...) i get a dictionary with several items with different ids and geometries?!
i wanted to do that with the list of dictionaries, because i couldn't find anything for storing several items (like in a excel table) in a dictionary...

Comment: notice `defaultdict(list)` uses the builtin `list` which is why you should **never** use `list` for a variable name

Comment: A dictionary is a mapping from any (hashable) type to any type of data. The canonical dictionary maps strings to strings (`dict["spam"] = "ham"`) but this is not the only thing you can do. In this case, THC4k is mapping a string (the `id` of a point) to a list of points with those `id`s. The `collections.defaultdict` means that a string we haven't processed yet maps to `[]`.

Comment: ok, so i will have one entry for the id and to that several point-geometries... 
mh, i think i have to find another solution, because the calculation of the points itself takes already a lot of time... and they are stored to the list of dictionaries... so i will have to change the calculation, because otherwise i am storing these points during the calculation to the list of dictionary and then convert it to a dictionary.... thats not very clever...
so you think it will be too much trouble to make that loop with the second entry?!?!

Comment: @pythonacc: It doesn't compute anything new, it just takes the points from your first list and puts them into a different dictionary. Of course you can skip generating the first list if you don't need it elsewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you want to do, but I think list filtering would help you. There's built-in function `filter`, which iterates over a sequence and for each item it calls user-defined function to determine whether to include that item in the resulting list or not.

For instance:

```
def is4(number):
   return number == 4

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 4, 4]
filter(is4, l) # returns [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

So, having a list of dictionaries, to filter out all dictionaries with certain entry equal to a given value, you could do something like this:

```
def filter_dicts(dicts, entry, value):
   def filter_function(d):
      if entry not in d:
         return False
      return d[entry] == value
   return filter(filter_function, dicts)
```

With this function, to get all dictionaries with the "id" entry equal to 2, you can do:

```
result = filter_dicts(your_list, "id", 2)
```

With this, your main loop could look something like this:

```
processed_ids = set()
for item in list:
   id = item['id']
   if id in processed_ids:
      continue
   processed_ids.add(id)
   same_ids = filter_dicts(list, "id", id)
   # now do something with same_ids
```

I hope I understood you correctly and that this is helpful to you.

Comment: oh great!!! thanks a lot... that looks good... i have to read it again and try it with mine!