# loop through values from a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Given a list of dictionaries in python like this:

```
dict_list = [
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2},
{'c' : 2, 'd' : 3},
{'x' : 4, 'y' : 5, 'z': 0}
]
```

What is the best to loop through all the values while emulating the obvious:

```
for i in dict_list:
    for x in i.values():
        print x
```

But ideally avoiding the nested `for` loops. I'm sure there must be a better way but I can't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-for-loops-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458285/loop-through-list-of-dictionaries

Comment: @devnull neither of those posts help me.

Comment: @nettux443 What else do you expect?

Comment: @thefourtheye sshashank124's answer is more helpful

Comment: @nettux443 So you want a list?

Comment: @thefourtheye I want a cleaner way of doing what I show in my second code block

Comment: @nettux443 For me, your code is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: I'd like some explanation of the downvotes. This is not a duplicate post to the best of my knowledge, it's a reasonable, clear question and I've got a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Matthias it looks simple but I'd rather not have a loop inside a loop if I can help it.

Comment: @nettux443 sshashank's answer does have a loop inside a loop. It is just not nested.

Comment: @Davidmh **read my question**. Last line: "But ideally avoiding the nested ````for```` loops". sshashank124's answer is really a ````for```` **followed by** a ````for```` loop as the entire list is generated before I start iterating over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through all the values, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
from itertools import chain

dict_list = [
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2},
{'c' : 2, 'd' : 3},
{'x' : 4, 'y' : 5, 'z': 0}
]

for item in chain.from_iterable(i.values() for i in dict_list):
    print item
```

Outputs:

```
 1
 2
 2
 3
 5
 4
 0
```

Comment: @thefourtheye, The OP has updated the question which makes it clearer

Comment: `list` spoils everything. It is not needed.

Comment: I would have settled with a generator expression, rather than chaining

Comment: @thefourtheye, I have removed the list.